# create a heatmap using R with 3 columns data

Tags: r, heatmap

I'm trying to create a heatmap using R with a csv file that looks like this:

[image]

I can load the file, convert as a matrix but when I call heatmap it gives an error:
Error in heatmap(as.matrix(vals)) : 'x' must be a numeric matrix.
If I remove the column ColName it works but then I don't know where are the values.

Can anybody gives me an idea on how to do the heatmap where I can have both values and the Colname in front or end of each line?
here are the lines that I'm using:
`vals <- read.csv(file = 'file.csv') heatmap(as.matrix(vals)) error in heatmap(as.matrix(vals)) : 'x' must be a numeric matrix`

Thank you very much

Raul

Comment: you should provide a minimal-reproducible-example. <https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example>.

Answer (score 0):

A matrix is a data object of a single type (such as numeric) with dimensions (rows and columns) defined.
This is different from a data.frame which is a data object where every column can be a different type.

```
con <- textConnection("
ColName,Val1,Val2
abc,0.22,0.86
def,2.41,1.09
ghi,3.13,1.50")
# data imported as a data.frame
vals <- read.csv(con)
# column_to_rownames from package tibble 
# adds rownames to a data.frame using a column
vals_matrix <- as.matrix(tibble::column_to_rownames(vals, var = "ColName"))
vals_matrix
#     Val1 Val2
# abc 0.22 0.86
# def 2.41 1.09
# ghi 3.13 1.50
heatmap(x = vals_matrix, margins = c(10, 10))
```

[image: output of stats::heatmap]

Answer (score 0):

To successfully create a heatmap, the matrix needs to be *entirely* numeric. Technically, you have a dataframe (i.e. a heterogeneous data structure; a structure with both numeric and categorical elements). The code below uses all base R commands and syntax. I've also attached the visual output as well.

```
dat <- data.frame(
  ColName = c("abc", "def", "ghi"),
  Val1 = c(0.22, 2.41, 3.13),
  Val2 = c(0.86, 1.09, 1.50)
)

heatmap(as.matrix(dat[, 2:3]), labRow = dat[, 1], Rowv = NA, Colv = NA)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your csv should contain only numeric variables. the heatmap function needs a matrix not a dataframe. If it is a dataframe convert it to matrix with as_matrix(vals):
Example:

```
vals <- matrix(c(0.22, 2.41, 3.13, 0.86, 1.09, 1.50), nrow = 2, ncol = 3)
rownames(vals) <- c("val1", "val2")
colnames(vals) <- c("abc", "def", "ghi")
heatmap(vals)
```

[image]